# Can someone explain what getItemCount method in RecyclerView.LayoutManager return?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

The documentation says the following about getItemCount():

> Returns the number of items in the adapter bound to the parent RecyclerView.
>   Note that this number is not necessarily equal to State#getItemCount().

So, does it return all the items in the adapter or the items that are visible on the screen? I don't get it. Can someone explain this method?

Comment: `getItemCount()` will return list size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **getItemCount() - returns The number of items currently available in adapter**

- This method returns the size of the collection that contains the items we want to display.

  ```
  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
      return models.size();
  }
  ```
- It returns The number of **items currently available in adapter**.

Reference:

- [getItemCount()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.State.html#getItemCount())
- [More about layout manager and getItemCount()](http://wiresareobsolete.com/2014/09/recyclerview-layoutmanager-2/)

Answer (score 1):

It returns the size of all the items in the adapter not only the size of visible items. In simple term, getItemCount() returns the size for the whole adapter.

Comment: getItemCount does not set anything

Comment: *returns.. my mistake

Answer (score 1):

The `getItemCount()` method returns the number of list items.The number of items this adapter is adapting.

**Reference Code :**

```
ArrayList<Games> list;

    public int getItemCount() {
         return list.size();
    }
```

The `getItemCount()` method is return the number of items in the collection you're adapting, in above case `list`, which is just an array of Game objects. Arrays have a property that allows you to get their length which is all you need to return.

Answer (score 0):

`getitemCount()` return how many items you want to show in the recyclerView